# Define a bean name in configuration spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, javabeans

My spring boot app fails to start because of this error: `A component required a bean named 'sessionScopedLdapUser' that could not be found`

My beans are defined in this class:

```
@Configuration
public class RestTemplateClient {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SwitchController.class);

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }

    @Bean("sessionScopedLdapUser"); /************** <----
    @Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_SESSION, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
    public LdapUser requestScopedBean() {
        logger.info("LdapUser bean instance created");
        return new LdapUser();
    }
```

I use the bean in my service class:

```
@Service
public class IsimRestApiImpl implements IsimRestApiService{

    

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Resource(name = "sessionScopedLdapUser")
    LdapUser sessionScopedLdapUser;
```

I am not sure what I do wrong in the configuration. If I add the bean name in my Configuration (where the arrow is) I get `Annotations are not allowed here.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be that it has something to do with the scoping of your bean ? I also feel like you should not give the bean a name. If you only make one bean of LdapUser type, there is not need in my opinion ...

I'd try removing the name and the scope from the bean and see if your application starts. Before adding some options and figuring out where exactly it goes wrong.